# Missing Style Library in Site collection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am Newbie in SharePoint 2013. I am creating a site Collection and I want to add my png files on Style Library but I am having problem finding Style Library.
Is there any way to activate Style Library for Team Site or Site Collection?

The site I have created cannot be opened from SharePoint Designer 2013. I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013.
Is there any way out to edit page using SharePoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 3):

1. only the root site of site collections will contain a style library, not subsites
2. You should find the style library upon site creation, but you can try enabling the publishing infrastructure feature and see if that helps
3. as a last resort, you can create a new site collection, and save the style library as a template and add it to your site that is missing it

as for editing, you should use sharepoint designer, although you do have the possibility of creating a mapped folder in windows by using the url of your website

Answer (score 0):

With the sharepoint foundation, they is not possible to enabled the publishing infrastructures for the collection or the site itself, this option is available only on the sharepoint server 2013.

You can try to access by url : `http://MyWebSiteName/Style%20Library/Language*/Themable`

- language like this format : fr-fr

If it's ok, you can edit the file you want in the ribbon menu "File" (that's open it in SharePoint Design 2013, not in the sharepoint web site).

If it's not ok, maybe you don't have rights, or maybe the foundation version lock it...